# identifying a decoded string and what method to use for decoding

Tags: php, decode

I have a string that looks like this. That I need to decode.

```
DE9F6B7AB96AA0D5B01F8E51BE2B4D8951CC2C8A10E42F5EA1DB089D677BF15E
```

I am not sure what method is being used to encode this string so if someone could tell me what the method is and how to decode it?

Comment: That looks like a hash, but it could be anything. You're probably not going to be able to decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the length of the string (64 hex digits = 32 bytes = 32 x 8 = 256 bits), it appears to be [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) hash or one of these hashes: [BLAKE/GOST/Snefru(256)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) (if they are still in use)

By theory a hash, if it is created using a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), is supposed to be "infeasible to generate" back the original clear text. So, I doubt if you could decode this. [Crackstation](http://crackstation.net/index.php#cracking-hashes) yielded the type as "unknown" and failed to get its cleartext.